# Debuggin app published to IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis, web-applications

I have a problem with debugging app published to IIS.

I'm publishing to IIS by filesystem. The process is following:

1. publishing to filesystem
2. logging in to IIS machine
3. copy&paste published app to IIS folder

When I publish using default settings it all works fine except I can't debug my app (I can attach to IIS process, but there is no debug data in my published app).

I found out that there is option to precompile app before publishing and this option has option to emit debug data. I looked just what I needed, but it doesn't work. For example I can't log in to my app after publishing it that way.

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you publish, are you in debug or release mode? And do you have the remote debugger set up on the IIS machine to connect to?

Comment: @Sean I'm publishing in debug-like configuration (no optimizations and so on, very similar to default debug conifguration).
When I build (not publish), prepare files like conifgs, and then copy it to my IIS, debugging works fine - I can attach, debug. When I publish it in the same conifguration, np .pdb files are published. I can attach to it, but no breakpoints will be hit.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? I'm asking because when I choose to publish a site and I'm in debug mode, it publishes all the .pdb files along with the DLLs and such with no problem, I've not changed anything about my debug configuration either, it's all standard.

Comment: @Sean I'm using VS2012. Do you have "precompile" checked on your publish configuration?

Comment: I did at one point, as I thought it would help with speed but it didn't, so I unticked it.